# What is the difference between pow and powf

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

I try to solve a math problem and my output sensitivity has a little different such as 0.07. And then I compare `pow()` and `powf()` in my code and I see this sensitivity. The code as follows:

```
int main()
{

    int terms, sign=-1;
    double x, operation=0.0;

    printf("Please enter the number of terms : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &terms);

    while (terms <= 0)
    {
        printf("Please re-enter the number of terms :");
        scanf_s("%d", &terms);
    }

    printf("Please enter a value for x :");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);

    for (int i = 1; i <= terms; i++)
    {
    sign = sign * (-1);
    operation = operation + sign * powf(x + i / 10.0, (2 * i) - 1) / (2 * i);
    }
    printf("The result is : %.2lf\n", operation);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Sample:

```
terms  : 10

x : 1.1

output  : `-59783.61` with `powf`

output  : `-59783.67` with `pow`
```

What is the difference between to these functions?

Comment: [man pow](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html): `double pow(double x, double y)` and `float powf(float x, float y)`

Comment: Unrelated: please don't use _s functions, they are not any safer then their portable counterparts.

Comment: Rather than think of a difference of 0.07, consider a difference of 1 part in a 1,000,000 - about the precision of typical `float`.

Comment: The same as between `.1` and `.1f`.

Answer (score 5):

`pow` operates on `double`s. `powf` operates on `float`s. This is a fairly standard notation in C, where the base name of a function will be for operands (and return values) of the default type (like `int` and `double`), while prefixed and suffixed versions are for other types (like `long`, `float`, etc). Here is a reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/.

This difference in data types fully explains the differences you see in your result.

`double`s contain 53 bits of precision in the mantissa, which translates to ~16 decimal digits of precision. This exceeds the precision with which you display your result, so is probably accurate enough for your purposes.

`float`s, on the other hand, have only 24 bits in the mantissa, which translates to ~7 decimal digits. Any combination of operations will cause roundoff errors do creep in almost immediately to within your display precision.

Answer (score 2):

The C language did not have "generic functions" until C11. Instead, there are different functions in the standard library for different data types.

The `*f`  functions of `<math.h>` operate on single-precision floating point numbers (`float`s using single precision internally. `double` stands for ... double precision. Always use the non-`f` functions for double arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is :

```
float powf( float base, float exponent );
double pow( double base, double exponent );
```

**DESCRIPTION [in here](http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/math.h/pow.php?alias=powf)**

> The `pow` functions compute `base` raised to the power of `exponent`.

Comment: What source are you quoting?

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed a necessary improvement. It is very important to credit your source, especially when you make a direct quote like that.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) , `pow` takes a `double`, where `powf` takes a `float` rendering it much less precise.

Answer (score 0):

`powf` returns and takes arguments of `float`.

`pow` returns double and takes arguments of `double`. If a float number is given as parameter, it is converted to `double` by the usual promotion rules.[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

The difference you are seeing in the result is due to the higher precision of `double`